# Há concordância de particípio com pronome (por exemplo, os)?

Tags: concordância

Se a frase **"Nós temos aceitado os documentos"**

for escrita assim: **"Nós os temos aceitado"** ou **"Os temos aceitado"**

O particípio **"aceitado"** deveria concordar com "os"? Quero dizer, nesse caso, o correto seria **"aceitados"**?

Tirei esse exemplo de "Moderna Gramática Portuguesa" de Bechara, 38ª edição, página 243. Não encontrei exemplos que combinam o pronome "os" com a conjugação composta.

Ele observa que "Em geral emprega-se a forma regular [do particípio], que fica invariável com os auxiliares *ter* e *haver* na voz ativa." Então acredito que o particípio seja "aceitado" nos dois casos. Mas não tenho certeza.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, o particípio quando usado mesmo como particípio, e não como adjetivo, com o verbo auxiliar *ter* (ou *haver*) é invariável em número e género, independentemente de o objeto ser um pronome ou não:

> Nós temos aceitado os documentos
> Nós os temos aceitado / (forma canónica em Portugal) nós temo-los aceitado
>
> Nós temos aceitado as mercadorias
> Nós as temos aceitado / (forma canónica em Portugal) nós temo-las aceitado

Podes ver [este artigo no Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/adjectivo-vs-participio-passado/24270) sobre os vários usos do particípio.

Descobri uma “meia exceção” nesta [Mini Gramática online](http://www.nilc.icmc.usp.br/nilc/minigramatica/mini/oparticipioeaexpressaohajavista.htm), que é a locução *haja vista*, em que o particípio vai sempre para o feminino (exemplo deles):

> Hoje sairei daqui mais tarde, **haja vista** o trabalho que ainda tenho de terminar.

Mas iste *haja vista* deve ser visto como uma locução fixa, e não como uma conjugação normal do verbo *ver*.

### Particípio e Adjetivo

Agora, a título de curiosidade, nós podemos ter construções com o particípio e adjetivo quase idênticas, só que o adjetivo concorda em número e género com o nome. Exemplo com o verbo catalogar (*aceitar* não seve porque o adjetivo é diferente do particípio):

> Então e as revistas que têm chegado recentemente?
>
> (a) Tenho-as catalogad**o** (à medida que chegam)
>
> (b) Tenho-as catalogad**as**

Em (a) temos o particípio passado do verbo *catalogar*, e *ter* é verbo auxiliar. Já em (b), *ter* é verbo principal e *catalogadas* é adjetivo; é equivalente a dizer “eu tenho as revistas, ou elas estão de algum modo sob a minha responsabilidade, e já estão catalogadas”.

Comment: Aqui diz que _vista_ é nome (semelhante a _tendo em vista_): https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/FAQresposta.php?id=49

Comment: @Artefacto, interessante. Ficaste convencido com o argumento deles? A comparação com *tendo em vista* não me parece completamente justa. Tomando *vista* como nome, parece ficar a faltar algo, e.g. "haja vista **do** trabalho..."

Comment: Segundo Bechara, existe ainda a possibilidade da expressão "Haja vista" com significado de "veja" ocorrer como: "Hajam vista os seguintes exemplos" (considerando-se o substantivo no plural como sujeito). Mas de qualquer forma, "vista" não muda. Mini Gramática Online aponta "Hajam vistas" como inadequado, mas não inclui "Hajam vista".

Comment: @Heitor, creio que também vi isso algures. É uma construção curiosa. Eu não conhecia; creio que aqui em Portugal não se usa (muito?).

Comment: @Jacinto Sim, o autor admite que "a construção mais natural e frequente" é "haja vista". O exemplo de "Hajam vista" que ele citou foi escrito por Cândido de Figueiredo, mas não especifica em qual obra dele.

Comment: Not the right place to say it, but "welcome back".

Comment: @Centaurus,obrigado. Eu nunca me fui embora de todo. Ando só mais ocupado com outras coisas.

Comment: @Heitor, eu refiro-me às duas, *haja vista* e *hajam vista*. Nunca tinha ouvido qualquer delas; provavelmente caíram em desuso em Portugal. Talvez valesse a pena uma pergunta sobre a origem e análise gramatical da expressão? É deveras curiosa. Vi no dicionário de Cândido de Figueiredo (1939), mas não vem nada.

Comment: Sim, Jacinto, "haja vista" é uma locução fixa, da mesmo forma que "pelo visto".  Eu uso com certa frequência.  Aliás, valia a pena uma pergunta englobando "tendo visto", "pelo visto", "tendo em vista" e "haja vista".  Pelo visto tu irias responder, haja vista o interesse que a locução despertou em terras de ultramar.  (ultramar para nós é Portugal, etc)  Quanto a "hajam vista" nunca ouvi e soa muito estranho.